# Determining which version of a layout was set / loaded

Tags: android

I've got two versions of an activity layout, one for landscape and a default (portrait) version.   In the code below, after setContent, I want to do some condition code depending upon what layout was loaded.  Eventually it might not just be as simple as looking at the orientation, there might be more layouts dependent upon screen size, etc.  Just trying to figure out which version of the layout it has loaded without trying to write the same conditional logic myself.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a string tag the root views of the layouts. E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="landscape">
    ...
```

You could then check the tag after the view has been inflated and know from which resource type it came from.

```
when(rootView.tag) {
    "landscape" -> ...
    "portrait" -> ...
}
```

Comment: I am going to accept this as the answer as it does do what I wanted, for adding an extra tag to the layout it allows the code to be 100% sure which layout was used.  I do also like @ataulm's answer but it does require the resources to be set up in the same way as the layouts and could allow mistakes to be introduced.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do conditional stuff like this, you can use a boolean value resource (or integer value if you have more than two configurations), putting one in each configuration you're testing.

`/res/values/foo.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <bool name="is_landscape">false</bool>
</resources>
```

`/res/values-land/foo.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <bool name="is_landscape">true</bool>
</resources>
```

And you can check by resolving the value:

```
if (resources.getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This is a useful answer and I've got it working.  Someone else replied using tag in the view, not sure why they deleted their answer.  Both worked, I kind of liked the tag version as I could get it from the view and it couldn't 'lie' where as with this answer, whilst it works and is good, you have to ensure you've got your resources set up with same conditions as the layouts

Comment: @PaulHadfield I deleted my answer because I think this method is cleaner. You just have to define the values once while with tags you have to define them for each layout. Anyway I un-deleted if it could be useful

Comment: yeah I think it's worth leaving both - I didn't consider using tags.